# XSL TR and TD elements with attributes and values and CSS

Tags: html, css, xslt

**MOST RECENT UPDATE** I have included a sample XSL and current output :)

**SAMPLE XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
  >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/Report">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
        </xsl:text>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
            <head>
                <title>My Report</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <xsl:element name="table" namespace="">
                <xsl:element name="tr" namespace="">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">123</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="td" namespace="">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">width: 15%;</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="div" namespace="">
                            mememe
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <xsl:element name="td" namespace="">
                        <xsl:element name="div" namespace="">
                            hi there
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <xsl:element name="td" namespace="">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">width: 3%; text-align:center; padding:0px;</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="div" namespace="">
                            no chance
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>My Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table xmlns="">
            <tr id="123">
                <td style="width: 15%;">
                    <div>
                            mememe
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                            hi there
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 3%; text-align:center; padding:0px;">
                    <div>
                            no chance
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**THE PROBLEM** The xmlns="" breaks my strict HTML validation as well as all subsequent css. How do i get rid of it? Thank you!

**Don't scroll down unless you want to see how it started**

---

**EDIT** I need an attribute `id` for the tr tag because i need to assign the value so i can use it as an anchor point.

**CODE**

```
<xsl:template match="Details">
<xsl:element name="tr">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::PluginID"></xsl:value-of>
       <xsl:element name="td">Mall 3</xsl:element>
       <xsl:element name="td">00003</xsl:element>
        <td class="medium">
            <div>
                <a href="#top">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="darkstyle" style="width: 3%; text-align:center; padding:0px;">
            <div>
                    <a href="#top">Top</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**ISSUE**

I can't use the `xsl:element` to add `<td>` and i can't use the `html <td>` tag either. **So how do i do this**? There are TD have classes and other style that needs to be applied `inline` and they should all have a `<div>` with some value in it.

Unless is there another way to assign the value of `PluginID` to `<tr>`?

And then how do i add the actual `<div>` and it's value into there?

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

**EDIT** I got the classes to apply and it transforms without error but the CSS `<style>` tag is not being applied, only the style from the class is! Any ideas?

```
<xsl:element name="tr">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::PluginID"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            medium
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            width: 15%;
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::RiskDesc"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            medium
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            darkstyle
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            width: 3%; text-align:center; padding:0px;
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="div">
            Top
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
<tr xmlns="" id="10026">
    <td class="&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;medium&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" style="&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;width: 15%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;">
        <div>Medium</div>
    </td>
    <td class="&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;medium&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;">
        <div>Derp Derp</div>
    </td>
        <td class="&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;darkstyle&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;" style="&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;width: 3%; text-align:center; padding:0px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;">
        <div>
            Top
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT** SIMPLIFIED EXAMPLE:

```
<xsl:element name="div">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        darkstyle
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- THE ISSUE IS THAT THIS STYLE ATTRIBUTE IS NOT BEING APPLIED! -->
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        width: 3%; text-align:center; padding:0px;
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:element name="div">
        Top
    </xsl:element>  
</xsl:element>
```

**ASSOCIATED CSS**

```
.darkstyle{
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background:#666;
}
```

**UPDATE** One of the issues was that I had tabs which were being turned into escaped characters use

`<xsl:attribute name="class">darkstyle</xsl:attribute>`

on **ONE** line and it will create the proper html.

I managed to track the break to the `<tr>` tag, the above code, generates the following:

`<tr xmlns="" id="10020">`

It is this `xmls=""` that breaks all of my CSS. **What can i do about this?** FYI: I tried adding `namespace=""` to the `tr` but that didn't prevent it.

**TOP OF XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  version="1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="yes"
  >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/Report">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
        </xsl:text>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
            <head>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to next several elements inside an attribute?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I need to assign an id value to the `tr` and i need to create `td's` which have styles applied. I don't understand your question. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: maybe you can provide us with inputs that we can use to reproduce the error

Comment: What is with all the equal signs in your edited version?  Those shouldn't be there as they will cause you to end up with elements looking like `<td class="=darkstyle" style="=width: 3%"/>` which is not going to be processed correctly.

Comment: @Joel M. Lamsen I update the XSL example and added my working CSS class. Input isn't required to replicate this issue. When using `<xsl:attribute name="style">` The **inline CSS** defined there is not being applied to the output html.

Comment: @Matthew Sorry, they got added when i was editing in notepad. They aren't actually in the code or part of the issue :)

Comment: I traced the issue to the `xmls=""` tag that is generated in the `<tr>` any ideas what i can do about this? Or how i can prevent it from being generated. Or why it's even there?

Comment: I added an answer addressing your namespace problem.  What processor are you using?

Comment: @Matthew for the transformation? JAXB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processor is adding an empty default namespace to all of your rows.  This is causing your browser to get confused on if the *tr* elements should be treated as table rows or not.

To fix this, you can put all non-namespaced elements into the default namespace by declaring this default namespace on your stylesheet root.

Additionally, the *exclude-result-prefixes* attribute expects a list of prefixes, not a yes/no value.  This is the list of namespace prefixes you don't want to be attached to the resulting document.  In your case, it is `xsl`.  Many processors would cause an error with an invalid value there, but for some reason yours apparently is not.

On your `xsl:stylesheet` element add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, and change the *exclude-result-prefixes*, so that it reads

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        version="1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
```

---

Additionally, avoid specifiing an empty namespace with the `namespace=""` attribute on the dynamic elements unless they explicitly need an empty namespace (ie are not HTML elements).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, please see update above. That didn't remove the xmlns="" tag :(

Comment: @codeCompiler77 Remove all of the `namespace=""` attributes.  Those are overriding the default namespace and are the source of your problem.

Comment: **Sir! You are a gentleman and a scholar. I thank you kindly!** :) If it's not too much trouble, would you mind explaining why the xsl exclusion worked? What is the XSL exclusion specifically. I had tried xhtml in there before i tried yes/no which i saw in a stackoverflow accepted answer :(

Comment: @codeCompiler77 That attribute is simply a list of prefixes for namespaces that you don't want to be attached to the result.  In many cases you have multiple ns used in the document (if you need to do date manipulation you will need namespace to pull in the date functions).  All of those will end up in the result document.  By specifying them there, you avoid writing them out.  I'm not sure why you would have seen 'yes' used (in fact that should have caused an error).  In your case, however, you don't actually need that attribute at all as the xslt prefix is not written out by default.

Comment: @codeCompiler77 Here is where it is discussed [in the XSLT specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element).

Comment: thank you for the explanation and the link. Going to read it over and go sleep after, have a great night! This was the last little piece i needed to get my XHTML Strict compliant. Now i get to work on a PDF/Google Doc export, fun! :)